# What's the /metrics endpoint for InfluxDB Cloud?

Tags: prometheus, influxdb, metrics

Any idea what's the `/metrics` endpoint for InfluxDB Cloud? There are only references for [Influxdb OSS](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/monitor-alert/templates/monitor/#set-up-influxdb-oss-for-monitoring), but need to scrape some metrics also from my cloud instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from InfluxDB employee:

> There isn’t sadly since we mange and maintain the cluster. You can
> find certain metrics exposed via Flux but I am not sure if these are
> valid with IOx I would need to check.

Comment: what metrics are you looking for?